# Can Windows 7 Paint (aka Microsoft Paint) handle transparency?

Tags: windows-7, images, microsoft-paint, image-transparency

I need to edit a small image that uses transparency bits.  I edited it in Paint that is included in Windows 7, and lost all the transparency.

Can the Paint app that is included with Windows 7 (aka Microsoft Paint) handle PNG files that use transparency?

I looked through all the options, and didn't see anything except for an option under Selection Options, which serves a different function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Windows paint does not support transparency, although using color purple RGB: 255,0,255 could be used as a transparent color. Some programs pick it up, but MS Paint does not natively support transparency.

[Paint.net](http://getpaint.net) (free program) does support transparency, and is easy to use. It even does support alpha-transparency.

Comment: Thanks.  I've never heard of using rgb(255,0,255) for transparency... learn something new every day.

Comment: If you open a PNG with transparency in it, the transparency will be converted to purple.

Comment: I'm not seeing that in MS Paint.  The transparency showed up as white.  When I saved it, it got converted to real white pixels.

Comment: Ah okay. That does confirm that MS Paint can't handle transparency.